# Matplotlib: Two histograms on the same plot (shared x-axis)?

Tags: matplotlib, histogram

I have a dataframe where I've filtered the values of one column into two groups: outliers and standard. I have the two groups in separate lists and I want to create 2 histograms- one for outliers and one for standard data- and have them displayed together on the same plot and have them share the axis.

The code I started with loops through the two groups and passes them to seaborn.dist(), but the second data set resets the scaling on the x_axis and the outlier group is hardly visible. Lately I've been going through the matplotlib tutorials and am about to read about compound paths in the Path tutorial.

A colleague was able to achieve the result using R, but I'm trying to work it out in matplotlib.

Answer (score 0):

It is also achievable with Matplotlib easily. 
You can do it either with seaborn and matplotlib or matplotlib alone. Below is the first version using seaborn to plot histograms. You can adjust xlimits using `ax.set_xlim(min_value,max_value)`

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
data=np.random.normal(5,1,100)
outliers=np.random.normal(10,.5,100)
fig,ax=plt.subplots()
sns.distplot(data,ax=ax)
sns.distplot(outliers,ax=ax)
ax.set_xlim(0,15)
```